# Debris in headlamp assembly, fire hazard?

Tags: hyundai, headlight, santa-fe, fire-hazard

I just finished replacing my HIDs on my 2014 Hyundai Santa Fe Limited.  Aside from having to remove the front end it was quite easy.

However, as I was replacing one of the bulbs I noticed what I think is some of the reflector material peeled off. I'm guessing from age.

As I turned the headlamp assembly around, up and down, etc, as I was removing the bulb, some of that came loose and somehow wound its way into the front of the headlight. I'll attach a picture, but what I mean by that is that with the headlight installed properly you can see little flakes of the reflective material.

I used a pretty powerful shop vac to try to vacuum some of it out and just inverting the light and shaking it a little bit let some of it fall out on its own. But there is still debris in there.

My ultimate goal is to replace the two headlight units because they are old and the reflective material isn't doing the best job. But I don't plan on doing that for a couple months. Mostly due to the cost.

For now, I'm just wondering if this is a fire hazard?  My understanding is those bulbs can get pretty hot. But the material was already in there anyways and it's doing just fine. Now it's just in the front of the headlight.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry the picture I took is too large to upload. I'll work on getting a copy up.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!